# sets notation write the element of A

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

Can anyone help me to do this? and explain a little bit on your answer.

Comment: What is `Z`? $$

Comment: don't know that image was the original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is so badly written that it is hard to figure out what it means.
Apparently it is using an Euro sign as if it were a set membership sign, and I don't think anyone who's actually familiar with the underlying mathematics would make the mistake, so I think it must have been typed in from a handwritten draft by someone who doesn't actually understand it.

One possibility is that what was meant was
$$ A = \{ x \mid x \in \mathbb Z^+, 2>x-3 \} $$
in which case $A$ would have finitely many elements such that it makes sense to write it down explicitly by elements.

Comment: My educated guess: It's been typed by some high school teacher - preferably in Microsoft Word... (If that's true, the Euro sign gave it away.)

Comment: @Stefan: That would perhaps explain the Euro sign, but not the "Z" to the left of the greater-than sign.